# Magento 2 checkout error message translation

Tags: magento2, translation, checkout

I can't translate the top checkout error message "The requested qty exceeds the maximum qty allowed in shopping cart", the item error message translates ok. Where is the location of this piece of code?:

```
<div class="message message-error error"><div data-ui-id="checkout-cart-validationmessages-message-error">The requested qty exceeds the maximum qty allowed in shopping cart</div></div>
```

[checkout attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF8mf.png)

[checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkxMA.png)

Answer (score 0):

This message is located in the file:
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/messages.html

You can modify this file to change the message.

Comment: Hi, I haven't this file where you say, see attached file "magento" I've added in my question, I'm using magento cloud 2.4.2, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To find where the message file is located, you can enable the Magento 2 debug template functionality to highlight the template file:

To enable template hints:

**Click Stores > Settings > Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer**

In the Scope: dropdown in the upper-left corner, select the view for which you want the template hints.

In the Debug tab, set Template Path Hints for the storefront to Yes.

To enable path hints for Admin, set Template Path Hints for Admin to Yes.

To save the changes, click Save Config in the upper-right corner.

Use the bin/magento dev:template-hints:enable command to enable template hints and the bin/magento dev:template-hints:disable command to disable them.

**Other Way**

Once you find the file path, although, in Magento 2, the messages are in CSV format for every module, i.e., in vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/i18n/en_US.csv. You can change and customize your messages in this file for the module.
That's it

Comment: Hi Jyotishina, I already tried what you mention before, but returns: vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/messages.phtml, that contains only:  <div data-placeholder="messages"></div>, Thanks!!

Comment: Hi @Xavi please check the file: vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n/en_US.csv for your message if not found please check another module too to change and configure your message, I have to change the description also.

Comment: Hi @Jyotishima, I I have done the translation in my_theme/i18n/es_ES.csv, and you can see in "checkout attachment" that is working for the item message but don't works for the top message :( Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, @Xavi did you check your message where it is exactly in a module? your message in vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/i18n/enUS.csv, you are not overriding your message in the correct located file, please check the correct file message so you can override in app/design, i.e, in your theme. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Jyotishima, the message is in vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Model/IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition/IsCorrectQtyCondition.php, I tried to put the translation in "app/design/frontend/my_theme/mu_theme/i18n/es_ES.csv", "app/design/frontend/my_theme/Magento_CatalogInventory/i18n/es_ES.csv" and "app/design/frontend/my_theme/Magento_CatalogInventorySales/i18n/es_ES.csv". The message: "The requested qty exceeds the maximum qty allowed in shopping cart", But it continues to translate only the product as the checkout attachment :(

Comment: I think the problem is when it generates the message inside <div class="message message-error error"><div data-ui-id="checkout-cart-validationmessages-message-error">, but I am not able to find where create it

Comment: Hi @Xavi it is dynamically created <div class="message message-error error"><div data-ui-id="checkout-cart-validationmessages-message-error"> but your directory is not correct to translate the message. Did you directly change the message in vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/i18n/enUS.cs, just to debug if its working or not? Then you can your theme directory?

Comment: Also en_ES.csv is the language package so you can check and confirm this also

Comment: Hi @Jyotishima, in vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/i18n/en_US.csv, don't exists the text "The requested qty exceeds the maximum qty allowed in shopping cart", is in vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/i18n/en_US.csv, I changed in it directly but but it is not translated in the front either :( It has never cost me so much to translate a text in Magento... thanks!!!

Comment: Hi @Xavi, it's strange that you didnt find the vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/i18n/en_US.csv; you need to change "The requested qty exceeds the maximum qty allowed in the shopping cart", based on language and theme package. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Jyotishima, I find vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/i18n/en_US.csv, but not contains "The requested qty exceeds the maximum qty allowed in the shopping cart", this text is in vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/i18n/en_US.csv

Comment: Hi @Jyotishima, finally I solved the issue, is a magento bug, I applied the patch: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/31849

Comment: Hey @Xavi that's good to go

Answer (score 0):

This text is available in following path
vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Model/IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition/IsCorrectQtyCondition.php#112
You can change here But it would be more correct to change from translation file